# downloading pdf file using php and html link

Tags: php, html, pdf

i have written some code to select a row from a database and generate a link. the link is working ok but when i try to download the pdf i get this:

```
����)�^�z8��AQ�[��rr�=��73KJ��KR]�PD�H�����>3;,;~˾����ɫS����/ؤ���,������=??<8��3��L�����e�\I�aN�i.����A�.�����������|x�F�oN���1>MʙJ�#�Mz�'�N��?K��sx`D�5gژ�r&�N3��M�f����߱9<]R��,))�dj���D@k&O-�7V����M��d�I��HMN=��9��/�ubS���`189\S�����f�p_��T�T�&ӭ���E>�O�)eAœ
```

displaying on the page.

my code is:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * from table1 where invoice_number = '".$_GET["inv"]."' and sequence = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
    $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

    $file = 'http://www.domain.co.uk/invoices/'.$result["pdf"].'';
    $filename = 'Custom file name for the.pdf'; /* Note: Always use .pdf at the end. */

    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    @readfile($file);
}
?>
```

any ideas how i can make it download the file rather than try and display it in the browser. please note, its a shared hosting server so i cannot make many changes on the actual server itself

Comment: `$sql="SELECT * from table1 where invoice_number = '".$_GET["inv"]."' and sequence = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";` Don't populate `$_GET` vars to a query without sanitizing them. Better use prepared statements. Your code is higly vulnerable against SQL injections

Answer (score 2):

Change the following:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

to

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Comment: am still getting the same thing :(

Comment: @charliejsford Remove the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header declaration.

Comment: still the same, im getting this: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/integra/public_html/customer/index.php:3) in /home/integra/public_html/customer/downloadpdfinvoice.php on line 11

Comment: What is line #03 in `index.php`?

Comment: <?php include '../includes/settings.php'; ?>
then settings.php is just:

<?php
//contact details
$sql="SELECT * from contacts where sequence = '".$_SESSION["customer_sequence"]."' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$contact_sequence=$result["sequence"];

//company details
$sql="SELECT * from customer where sequence = '".$result["company_sequence"]."' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$company_sequence=$result["sequence"];
?>

Comment: settings.php is just to get the logged in contact and company etc

Comment: charliejsford Your select query in `settings.php` is not working. Please check the comment above by @hek2mgl for sanitizing